# Input.touchCount does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I am trying make the player shoot when touch in the screen, but does not work, look:

```
void Update ()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime; 

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {

            Touch myTouch = Input.touches[0];


            if (myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {


                Shoot ();
            }

        }
        ...
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to use Debug.Log?
Something like
void Update () {
        timer += Time.deltaTime; 

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {

            Touch myTouch = Input.touches[0];
            if (myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began){
              Debug.Log ("Began touch");
            }
           if (myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary){
               Debug.Log ("Stayed");
           
           }
           if (myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
                Debug.Log ("Ended Touch");
            
           }
    }
click on colapse on the console.

Answer (score 0):

The following will call `Shoot()` when you touch the screen:

```
void Update ()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime; 

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {               
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Shoot ();
        }
    }
}
```